# Kotlin OpenapiGenerator Any type generates into Map<String, JsonObject>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm struggling to find correct way to define Any object in Kotlin so that OpenApiGenerator would generate it as Object type.

I have a simple DTO object, payload is basically a map of object fields and values:

```
data class EventDto(
  val payload: Map<String, Any>,
  ...other fields

)
```

Which gets converted to OpenAPI Spec and looks like this:

```
ommited code
...
"payload": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "object"
  }
},
```

But when I execute open-api-generator
this get's converted into Kotlin class looking like this:

```
@Serializable
public data class EventPayloadDto(

    @SerialName(value = "payload")
    val payload: kotlin.collections.Map<kotlin.String, kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject>? = null,
)
```

Which is not so nice convert into because each object value needs to be converted to `JsonObject`, is it possible to retain "Any" object when generating from OpenAPI docs or I must use `Map<String, String>`?

I tried using objectMapper.convert

```
objectMapper.convertValue(event, object : TypeReference<Map<String, JsonObject>>() {})
```

but since there are no serializers into JsonObject it had no effect and ended up in an error.

Comment: Looks like a bug in whatever library you use to generate OpenAPI from Kotlin code. `Map<String, Any>` corresponds to just `type: object`, optionally with `additionalProperties: true`. `additionalProperties: {type: object}` is not the correct representation.

Comment: @Helen thank you it was the case, I've checked and in our project we had outdated version of opena-api generator https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator which was 5.0.0, I've tried with latest version and It generates source correctly!